# Kafka - Spark direct stream fail over

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, failover

We have a simple spark streaming application, streaming events from kafka through spark and persisting this into redis.

Initially we use the [Receiver-based Approach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-1-receiver-based-approach), which replicates the batches into HDFS and starts processing afterwards. This approach wasn't as stable as we whished (lot of traffic on our hadoop machines) so we switched to the [Direct Approach (No Receivers)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers) within spark streaming.

What confuses me is the **auto.offset.reset** parameter that is mentioned in the documentation. When a job failed or the sparkmaster went down, we would see the streaming jobs catching up by processing a large amount of events and then stabilizing overtime.

With the second approach we don't see this behaviour anymore and we are not sure if spark-streaming is really catching up or just starting at **auto.offset.reset** `latest`.

Is `latest` a sensible default for failover and does a streaming job really catches up correctly on restart/master-failure?

Thanks,
Muki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Zookeeper or if an
> offset is out of range:
>
> - smallest : automatically reset the offset to the smallest offset
> - largest : automatically reset the offset to the largest offset
> - anything else: throw exception to the consumer. If this is set to largest, the consumer may lose some messages when the number of
>   partitions, for the topics it subscribes to, changes on the broker. To
>   prevent data loss during partition addition, set auto.offset.reset to
>   smallest

This option takes place only when you run your job first time
or when some messages expire and the last committed offset in your consumer no longer exists.

So smallest is preferable if you do not want to lose data. If you restart job within the data expiry time this option doesn't affect your failover/restart